# Restart Outlook.exe as currently logged on user (remote system)

Tags: outlook-addin, psexec, runas

I'm trying to accomplish the following on a remote system:

1. Kill Outlook.exe
2. Run install.msi (silently)
3. Restart Outlook.exe (as the user that is currently logged onto the remote system).

The first two are easy:

1. `pskill  \\SYSTEMNAME -u username -p password outlook.exe`
2. `psexec.exe  \\SYSTEMNAME -u username -p password -i -d -low msiexec /i C:\Downloads\install.msi /quiet`

But the third is giving me trouble.  I've tried:

3. `psexec.exe  \\SYSTEMNAME -u username -p password -i -d -low "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe"`  (this starts Outlook, but as the user specified in the command)

   3*. `psexec.exe  \\SYSTEMNAME -i -d -low "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe"` (I thought removing the username/password in the command would run it as the currently logged in user, but this yields a strange box on the target system):

[image: wtf?]

3**. `psexec  \\SYSTEMNAME -u username -p password -i -d -w C:\Downloads\ -low "C:\Windows\System\RunAsCurrentUser.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Outlook.exe"` (the RunAsCurrentUser.exe utility can be downloaded from [here](http://software.bigfix.com/download/bes/util/RunAsCurrentUser-2.0.3.1.exe), but I'm thinking it might be only work within a different application)

3***. `psexec.exe  \\SYSTEMNAME -u username -p password -i -d -low "StartOutlook.bat"`  (this starts Outlook.bat, which contained the simple command "start Outlook.exe")

Any ideas how to get Outlook to start as the currently logged in user?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to automate Outlook from another machine. Have you considered using group policy objects for deploying the software on remote machines automatically?

Comment: Yes, I have the documentation available to push it out through Group Policy.  However, I wanted a manual way to do it because 1) I'm interested in general how to start processes on remote machines by impersonating a certain user and 2) the GP method seemed a bit complicated for this particular plugin, so I wanted to apply it for one user at a time so I could troubleshoot along the way (I know I could push it out per user through GP, but then there's the issue of refreshing  the policy and any other GP issues that might arise).

Answer (score 1):

I regret to tell you but the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) states the following:

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

As you may see the way you try to automate the task is not supported (non-intercative environment) because Outlook may display dialog in some cases. It simply can be stuck...

I'd recommend using the Group policy objects for deploying the software on remote machines instead.

Comment: I wonder why it works fine when I run it as a different user and provide the username/password?  I guess the problem is I don't have the username/password for the user I want to impersonate.  Thanks for the info.